# Destroying a model is passing in object Object as a parameter to server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have the following:

```
var folderEmail = Gmail.folderEmails.find(function (join) {   
    return (join.get('folder').id === starredFolder.id &&
    join.get('email').id === thisEmail.id)
});


folderEmail.destroy( {data: { folder: starredFolder, email: thisEmail }});
Gmail.folderEmails.remove(folderEmail);
```

When `folderEmail.destroy()` takes place, it sends a HTTP Delete request to the controller, and in the controller, as my params I get `{"object Object"=>nil, "action"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"folderjoins", "id"=>"67"}`. Why am I getting `"object Object" => nil`?

Comment: I'd guess that it is related to your `{data: { ... }}` but I don't see (off the top of my head) how that would happen. What happens if you take it out?

Comment: I also think it is related to that. The thing is that, then only the `id` gets passed along to the `destroy` action, but I need the extra data to do what I want to do in the action.

Comment: Can't you access that data via an ActiveRecord query before you destroy the record?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your hash doesn't get serialized when you pass it in.

If instead you do this:

```
folderEmail.destroy( {data: "folder=" + starredFolder + "&email=" + thisEmail });
```

You'll find that it works (at least in Backbone 1.0.0).